# ZF2 Curl not sending post values

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Im trying to use the native Zend Framework 2 http\curl libraries, I can get it to send the request to the remote application I am just unable to get it to POST values to it.

Here is my code that shows 2 examples, the first one is using native PHP curl and it works fine, the second one is using the ZF2 http\curl libraries and it does not pass any of the POST parameters.

Example 1 (Native PHP libraries)

```
    $url = $postUrl . "" . $postUri;

    $postString = "username={$username}&password={$password}";

    //This works correctly using hte native PHP sessions
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    var_dump($output); //outputs the correct response from the remote application
```

Example 2 (ZF2 library usage)

```
    $url = $postUrl . "" . $postUri;

    $postString = "username={$username}&password={$password}";

    //Does not work using ZF2 method!
    $request = new Request;

    $request->setUri($url);
    $request->setMethod('POST');

    $adapter = new Curl;

    $adapter->setOptions([
        'curloptions' => [
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postString,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
        ]
    ]);

    $client = new Client;
    $client->setAdapter($adapter);

    $response = $client->dispatch($request);

    var_dump($response->getBody());
```

Is anyone able to point out where i am going wrong with this? I have looked over the ZF2 documents but they are not the most comprehensive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the solution I used to fix this issue.

```
    $url = $postUrl . "" . $postUri;

    $request = new Request;
    $request->getHeaders()->addHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    ]);
    $request->setUri($url);
    $request->setMethod('POST'); //uncomment this if the POST is used
    $request->getPost()->set('username', $username);
    $request->getPost()->set('password', $password);

    $client = new Client;

    $client->setAdapter("Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl");

    $response = $client->dispatch($request);
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't really need to specify all those details on the `Curl` adapter. That is something ZF2 does for you:

```php
$url        = $postUrl . $postUri;
$postString = "username={$username}&password={$password}";

$client = new \Zend\Http\Client();

$client->setAdapter(new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl());

$request = new \Zend\Http\Request();

$request->setUri($url);
$request->setMethod(\Zend\Http\Request::METHOD_POST);
$request->setContent($postString);

$response = $client->dispatch($request);

var_dump($response->getContent());
```

Comment: Sorry for the amount of time it has taken to respond. This is causing an error because `$request->setBody($postString);` method does not exist.

Comment: My bad, it's `setContent`. Fixing the answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I ended up going with a different solution in the end. But this does appear to work as well.