# Passing session variable to external url in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Here's my code:

```
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();

        $session = $sm->get('SessionContainer');
        $client = $session->offsetGet('client');

    $url = "http://local.clients.com/"

    $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
```

I want to be able to pass $client to the $url e.g.

```
$this->redirect()->toUrl($url,$client);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15547869/1948627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the data to the query string:

```
$url = "http://local.clients.com/";
$url .= '?'.http_build_query(array('client' => $client));

return $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
```

Comment: Thanks it works. but is it possible to make it post? so data won't be seen

Comment: Nope. PHP can't prompt the user's browser to make a POST. Technically you could do that with JavaScript, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you have control over the site you're redirecting to, you could get that site to store the client value in a cookie and then redirect again to a URL without the query string. That would make it less obvious (but not invisible) to the user.